# Query to find tables without unique keys

Tags: sql, oracle

How can i find all the tables which doesn't have unique keys.
i have tried many queries , but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 2):

Use the `UNIQUENESS` field from the `ALL_INDEXES` table.

```
SELECT atc.table_name, atc.column_Name
FROM ALL_INDEXES ai
INNER JOIN ALL_IND_COLUMNS aic ON ai.OWNER = aic.INDEX_OWNER AND ai.INDEX_NAME = aic.INDEX_NAME
INNER JOIN ALL_TAB_COLUMNS atc ON atc.owner = col.table_owner AND atc.table_name = aic.table_name AND atc.column_Name = aic.column_Name
WHERE UNIQUENESS != 'UNIQUE';
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query will find all the tables in your logged-in schema which do not have either a PRIMARY or UNIQUE constraint:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME
  FROM (SELECT t.TABLE_NAME
          FROM USER_TABLES t
          WHERE t.TABLE_NAME NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT u.TABLE_NAME
                                       FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS u
                                       WHERE u.CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN ('U', 'P')) AND
                t.TABLE_NAME NOT IN (SELECT i.TABLE_NAME
                                       FROM USER_INDEXES i
                                       WHERE i.UNIQUENESS = 'UNIQUE'))
  ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
```

If you want to find *all the tables in the database* which lack either a primary or unique key you can use

```
SELECT DISTINCT OWNER, TABLE_NAME
  FROM (SELECT t.OWNER, t.TABLE_NAME
          FROM DBA_TABLES t
          WHERE (t.OWNER, t.TABLE_NAME) NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT c.OWNER, c.TABLE_NAME
                                                  FROM DBA_CONSTRAINTS c
                                                  WHERE c.CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN ('U', 'P')) AND
                (t.OWNER, t.TABLE_NAME) NOT IN (SELECT i.OWNER, i.TABLE_NAME
                                                  FROM DBA_INDEXES i
                                                  WHERE i.UNIQUENESS = 'UNIQUE'))
  ORDER BY OWNER, TABLE_NAME
```

### EDIT

@Matt makes a good point that it's possible to have a UNIQUE index which is not associated with a key/constraint, so I modified my queries to take advantage of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
select distinct t.table_name
  from user_tables t
 where not exists 
       ( select 0
           from user_constraints c
          where regexp_like(c.constraint_type,'u|p','i')
            and t.table_name = c.table_name )
```

**or**

```
select t.table_name
  from user_constraints c
 right join user_tables t
    on t.table_name = c.table_name
 group by t.table_name
having sum( case
            when c.constraint_type in ('U', 'P') then
               1
            else
               0
            end ) = 0
```

for only your current user.

For the whole database replace `user_` with `dba_` for the view names.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my favorite method for checking.  My concern is mostly when there are large tables with no unique index, since there may be reasons for small tables not to have them.

```
-- Large Tables With No Unique Index
-- 30-Aug-2019 RDCornejo
with exclude_owner as
(
select 'ORAAPPS' owner from dual union
select 'ORDDATA' owner from dual union
select 'MDSYS' owner from dual union
select 'SYS' owner from dual union
select 'SYSTEM' owner from dual union
select 'NIMMON' owner from dual union
select 'DBSNMP' owner from dual union
select 'CTXSYS' owner from dual union
select 'WMSYS' owner from dual union
select 'XDB' owner from dual 
)
select 
  'dba_indexes' metric_source
, 'Large Tables With No Unique Index' metric_name
, 1 metric_value
, 'Table Size (meg) [threshold=' || table_size_threshold || ' meg]: ' || table_size_meg  AS info 
, null metric_unit
, null metric_descr
, object_owner, object_name, object_type, null sub_object_name, null sub_object_type
from
(
select owner object_owner, table_name object_name, 'TABLE' object_type 
, status
, round((blocks * (select value from v$parameter where name = 'db_block_size'))/1024/1024) table_size_meg
, nvl(:table_size_threshold, 500) table_size_threshold
, temporary
, duration
from dba_tables a 
where 1=1
  and (owner, table_name) not in ( select owner, table_name from dba_indexes where uniqueness = 'UNIQUE' )
  and owner not in (select owner from exclude_owner)
  and owner like nvl(:owner, owner)
)
where 1=1
  and table_size_meg > nvl(:table_size_threshold, 500)
;
```